# New Identity providers for Sign-In User-Flow

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Since when does the Azure B2C Provide extra Identity Provider for the LogIn.
Where can I find the Update notes for that?

[screenshot-b2c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7iil.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can find
The latest releases
Known issues
Bug fixes
Deprecated functionality
Plans for changes, here in this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/whats-new#august-2021